# How to read from Go additional file descriptors when running a command

Tags: go

Let's say I have a program than outputs things on file descriptor 3; something like this:

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    fd3 := os.NewFile(3, "fd3")
    fd3.Write([]byte("FOOBAR\n"))
    fd3.Close()
}
```

Now, I want to get the output sent to file descriptor 3 from a Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("./client")
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    fd3 := os.NewFile(3, "fd3")
    defer fd3.Close()

    cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{fd3}

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            reader := bufio.NewReader(fd3)
            line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Print(line)
        }
    }()


    cmd.Wait()

    fmt.Println("--- END ---")
}
```

But that does not work as it outputs the following error:

```
panic: read fd3: bad file descriptor
```

I don't understand what's wrong with my code. Anyone willing to help?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that file descriptors are global, but they're per process. If you want to connect file desciptors in two processes, you need a pipe between them (in this case with one end of the pipe dup'd to fd 3 in the child).

Answer (score 3):

os.NewFile doesn't actually open a file descriptor.  It's really an API to wrap a fd that was given to you.

look at the godoc: http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create
(click the name Create, which currently points to [this](http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/file_unix.go?s=962:1005#L30))

I think you want to call os.Create(name) and pass the fd to the child process
or potentiall os.Open / os.OpenFile if you need to set mode and stuff

Comment: What if I have a program - say Asterisk PBX, that is feeding me a certain data (say EAGI) on a predetermined process FD of 3? How do I read a specific FD relative to the current process in Golang? I tried reading `os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("/proc/%d/fd/3", os.Getpid()))`, but my `io.Reader` seems to block on this, and a `cat` on the file says `Permission Denied`.